# Get Dialog's on click listener into my Activity from separate Dialog class

Tags: java, android, oop, android-studio, dialog

I have a Dialog class where I have kept my dialogs. Now the problem is that I want to get the View click listeners of my dialog back in my activity. I know this can be done by writing an interface but is there any other OOP way of doing it?

My Dialog class:

```
public class Dialogs{
 public void testCompletionDialog() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test_complete_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Ratta provet?");



        dialog.findViewById(R.id.lesson_btn_marker).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//I want my activity to know that this view is clicked.
                 dialog.dismiss();


            }
        });

        dialog.findViewById(R.id.lesson_btn_ratta).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //I want my activity to know that this view is clicked.


            }
        });

        dialog.show();


    }
}
```

My Activity:

```
if (areQueOver) {

                    Dialogs dialogs=new Dialogs(TestActivity.this);
                    dialogs.testCompletionDialog();
                }
```

Comment: IMHO you should use an `interface`.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes if you want to call any method of Actvity then you can call through context of Activity :

suppose method1() is under Activity and you want to call from Dailog then you can call through .

```
 ((MyActivity)((Activity)context)).method1();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. calling it without  making a method static. Thanks in deed.

Comment: Just to add you don't need to cast it to Activity here as (MyActivity) already helps getting the idea of what we are referring you and context itself can work here anyways. Casting to Activity give redundant casting warning.

Answer (score 2):

You may use it using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Inside your onClick in your Dialog class post an event telling that a dialog has been clicked. The event may contain a string variable telling which dialog is clicked.

Inside your Activity subscribe to and handle the event. You may check the String variable value to know which dialog was clicked.

**Modify your Dialogs class as below:**

```
public class Dialogs{
 public void testCompletionDialog() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test_complete_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Ratta provet?");

        dialog.findViewById(R.id.lesson_btn_marker).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 EventBus.getDefault().post("btn_marker");
                 dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.findViewById(R.id.lesson_btn_ratta).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post("btn_ratta");
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

**Inside your Activity:**

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN) public void onEvent(String action){
        if(action.equals("btn_ratta")){

        } else if(action.equals("btn_marker")) {

        }
    }
```

inside onCreate add this-

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

inside onDestroy add this-

```
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
```

**Alternative method:**

Well, other than interface and EventBus, you may add a public method to your Activity say,

```
onDialogClicked(String dialogName){//TODO handle the click as per dialogName}
```

and then call this method from your onClick in your Dialogs class.

Comment: I see that is a nice library but using third party for such a small task inst worth it. And I could use an interface for this instead of using a third party. I'm looking for something in the android for this or at least a generic java way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, not for a small task, but if you are making an app then it's very useful.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check. Hope it;'s helpful now.

Comment: Yeah it actually is a very nice solution for apps where you got a lot of communication between classes however Chetan answer actually solves my problem here but your solution definitely showed a new way. +1 with thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface.

```
public interface OnDialogConfirmClickListener {
    void onDialogConfirmClick(Class parameter//or empty);
}
```

Implement this interface to your activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnDialogConfirmClickListener {
...
}
```

Send interface as parameter to Dialogs or testCompletionDialog method.

```
public void testCompletionDialog(OnDialogConfirmClickListener listener) {
    ...
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.lesson_btn_marker).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     listener.onDialogConfirmClick(parameter//or empty);
                     dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use listner for call buttons like this

```
Simpledialoginterface listner = new Simpledialoginterface() {
    @Override
    public void ok_button() {
        //ok button click
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel_button() {
       //cancel button click
    }
};
```

use this dialog

```
public static void popupnew(String tittle, String message, String Button, String Cancel,
                            final Activity context, final Simpledialoginterface listner) {

    if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
        } else {
            alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        }
        alertDialog.setTitle(tittle);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(Button,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        listner.ok_button();


                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(Cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        listner.cancel_button();

                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

//interface class
`public interface Simpledialoginterface {`

```
public void ok_button();

public void cancel_button();
```

}

```
    popupnew("title","message","OK","Cancel",this,listner);//call dialog
```