# Calling a function within a custom alert dialog in activity

Tags: android, dialog, alert

I have a custom alert dialog which I am calling in my activity. The okay button is supposed to call a function but what happens is that the Button which is prompting the dialog causes the function to run before the user clicks okay on the alert dialog. Help!

Comment: Attach your code.

Comment: Share Your Code Please.

Comment: @codeon you can edit the question and insert the piece of code you think is causing the issue.

Comment: I came across a similar question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572674/get-dialogs-on-click-listener-into-my-activity-from-separate-dialog-class] and  a solution by @faranjit worked.